# Binding jQuery events before DOM insertion

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery

My problem is that I have to create event listeners on certain DOM elements before I insert them into the dom.

Now generally this is quite easy like so:

```
var button = $('<button>Click Me</button>');

button.on('click', function(){ alert('clicked'); });

$('body').append(button);
```

However, the problem is that I need to wrap the button in other html as in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/a8xjJ/

The Event Listener breaks if I mix the button object with a string of html.
That's when the Event Listener looses touch with the object, quite logically.

My problem is that I need to use strings of html, that's a constraint of the project. Maybe there is a way in which I can use the dom selector on a string? Or maybe you can think of another way of making the above fiddle work.

Comment: I'm guessing this is what you're trying to do -> [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/a8xjJ/1/) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you started to work with objects, try not to use their string representation (it outputs the *shell* only but not the events and other data). One possible solution of you problem:

```
$("<button>Click Me</button>").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Clicked");
}).wrap("<form><div></div></form>").closest("form").appendTo("div");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/a8xjJ/2/

Answer (score 4):

You can bind the dynamic elements by using [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function of JQuery.

I have updated your fiddle to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/a8xjJ/3/).

```
var button = $('<button>Click Me</button>');
var html = '<form>' + button.clone().wrap('<div/>').parent().html() + '</form>';
$('div').append(html);

$(document).delegate(button,'click', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    alert('Clicked');
});
```

You may also use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind the events on dynamic elements.

```
$(document).on('click', button, function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    alert('Clicked');
});
```

Notice that this method takes event as its first parameter.

Comment: Both the answers solve my problem, shame I can't tick them both. But I can vote yours up! Thanks!